# Is there a good way to temporarily prevent ActiveRecord from performing queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a set of ActiveRecord models which I am pre-loading in order to avoid N+1 issues. In order to help that process along, I'd like to be able to do some manual testing where I have (conceptually) blocks that look like the following:

```
# Prepare some data
data = Foo.includes(:bar, {baz: :quux}).find(27)

ActiveRecord.raise_error_if_any_queries_occur
perform_some_work_with_data(data)
ActiveRecord.back_to_normal
```

This seems like there *should* be a way to do it, but I haven't had any luck. Has anyone else done this?

Comment: slightly related - http://stackoverflow.com/q/26247288/525478

Comment: If you want to defer the query, why are you doing the `.find(27)` right away?

Comment: @lurker -- That happens beforehand. I do not want to defer the query, I want to do it all ahead of time, and then during the section where I am doing work I want to avoid implicit queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disconnect ActiveRecord from the database and reconnect it when you are finished:

```
data = Foo.includes(:bar, {baz: :quux}).find(27)

Foo.connection.disconnect!
perform_some_work_with_data(data)
Foo.connection.reconnect!
```

This will raise an error if anything tries to run a query against the database while ActiveRecord is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You can disconnect from database by following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from database')

perform_some_work_with_data(data)

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
Rails.logger.info('Connected to database')
```

But I think it's a little bit weird. And I prefer using [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) gem for N+1 query detection.

Answer (score 0):

Queries in rails will at some point call the `select_all(arel, name = nil, binds = [])` method as defined here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89a7187cc0d893da67f53d3215a33043905d68ed/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L22

You can see that this method will handle the query to the `select(sql, name = nil, binds = [])` method. Furthermore, this method handles the query to his parent method because of the use of undef_method :select which you can se in it's definition:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89a7187cc0d893da67f53d3215a33043905d68ed/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L354

Finally, this means that the select method that is executed is the ConnectionAdapter method, for example the posgresql adapter, as you can see in line 946 of:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89a7187cc0d893da67f53d3215a33043905d68ed/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb

So, first option: 
-You could edit one of those files to include some information that they were called, in a log for example.

Second, I don't know if it would work:
- You could rewrite the `select_all(arel, name = nil, binds = [])` to raise an exception like:

```
  def select_all(arel, name = nil, binds = [])
    raise "error"
  end
```

and when you want to cancel this overwrite you would undef your method with:

```
undef_method :select_all
```

So you would pass the select_all to the parent.

But Again, I don't know if the second works, but the first certainly works, although it's very invasive to edit rails core to include a log functionality.

Answer (score -2):

If you remove `find(27)` and use `where(id: 27)` you can append `.to_sql` to the end.

```
data = Foo.includes(:bar, {baz: :quux}).where(id: 27).to_sql
```

and then later execute it with:

```
Foo.find_by_sql(data)
```

You can also accomplish the same thing with [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel).  Arel will let you build more complex queries which you can execute when you so desire.