# Reduce N+1 Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

N+1 queries detected what does that mean what should i do to make it work.

I am using Bullet gem for showing N+1 queries

```
user: kalyan
N+1 Query detected
  Emp => [:functions]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:functions]
N+1 Query method call stack
  /home/Documents/app/views/tics/show.html.haml:20:in `_app_views_tics_show_html_haml___2301551533476719406_237290860'
```

This is the message from bullet gem.

**_app_views_tics_show.html.haml**

```
- if (@tic.assigned_to == current_user.emp) or (current_user.emp_functions.map{|x| x.id}.include?(1) if current_user.emp_functions.present? )
              = best_in_place @tic, :subject
            - else
              = @tic.subject
```

help me to reduce n+1 query problem

**emp.rb**

```
has_many :emp_functions, inverse_of: :emp,dependent: :restrict_with_exception
```

belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :emp

**emp_functions.rb**

```
belongs_to :emp , inverse_of: :emp_functions

belongs_to :function
```

**function.rb**

```
has_many :emp_functions, dependent: :restrict_with_exception

has_many :emp, through: :emp_functions
```

**user.rb**

```
has_one :emp, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
```

Comment: semi-related - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26251892/525478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho, the most efficient way to get rid of this N+1 query is to alter the `current_user` method, adding `includes(:emp_functions)` to the `User.find` call. The way you do it depends on the way you handle your authentication. If you're using some kind of gem (`Devise` or `Sorcery` for example) you'll need to reopen those classes and alter the method, not forgetting to use `super`. If youэму written your own authentication, you'd be able to do that more easily.

Second thing I noticed is that you don't actually need to use `map` on your `user.emp_functions` in the view, provided that `emp_functions` is a `has_many` association on the `User` model. You can just flatten it to `current_user.emp_function_ids.include?(1)`. This will help you get rid of the N+1 query problem, but only in this particular case. If you do tackle the `emp_functions` of the current user often in many places, I'd recomend using the first path I described.

Third third thing, not directly relevant to the question is that I really don't think that code belongs in the view. You should move it to a helper or a decorator, keeping the view clean and readable.

Comment: plus 1 for the third thing

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `emp_function_ids' for #<User:0x00000012819f68>
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'

Comment: Please check the Model Code

Answer (score 0):

If `emp_functions` is a has_many association on your user model (and it seems like it is), You should be doing:

```
current_user.emp_function_ids.include?(1)
```

Comment: I'd think that it's better to edit the current_user method, so you don't tackle the emp_functions every time you need to find a user or get a list of users. It could be lots of data to get in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very specific solution to your issue and I advise against using it in a view

change `current_user.emp_functions.map{|x| x.id}.include?(1)` to

```
current_user.emp_functions.where(id: 1).exists?
```

This will result in 1 single query to the db everytime you hit the page containing it.

You can also remove that `if` statement to remove another db query.

Comment: didn't worked, would you please modify it in another way. what i mean was actually that query you gave me fetching proper record, but still N+1 Query Problem.

Comment: then the N+1 query problem happens somewhere else.