# Rails 4 Eager load limit subquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

Is there a way to avoid the n+1 problem when eager loading and also applying a limit to the subquery?
I want to avoid lots of sql queries like this:

```
Category.all.each do |category|
  category.posts.limit(10)
end
```

But I also want to only get 10 posts per category, so the standard eager loading, which gets all the posts, does not suffice:

```
Category.includes(:posts).all
```

What is the best way to solve this problem? Is N+1 the only way to limit the amount of posts per category?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26251892/525478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Eager+loading+of+associations)

> If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it will be ignored, returning all the associated objects

So given the following model definition

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :included_posts, -> { limit 10 }, class_name: "Post"
end
```

Calling `Category.find(1).included_posts` would work as expected and apply the limit of 10 in the query. However, if you try to do `Category.includes(:included_posts).all` the `limit` option will be ignored. You can see why this is the case if you look at the SQL generated by an eager load

```
Category.includes(:posts).all

Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."category_id" IN (1, 2, 3)
```

If you added the `LIMIT` clause to the posts query, it would return a *total* of 10 posts and *not* 10 posts per category as you might expect.

Getting back to your problem, I would eager load all posts and then limit the loaded collection using `first(10)`

```
categories = Category.includes(:posts).all
categories.first.posts.first(10)
```

Although you're loading more models into memory, this is bound to be more performant since you're only making 2 calls against the database vs. n+1. Cheers.