# How to avoid N+1 queries in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following request in controller:

```
  def show
    @statistics = Keyword.find(params[:id]).statistics.order(:word).paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page]
  end
```

And in one place of a view file I request a cache id parameter:

```
<td><%= link_to "Open", cache_path(stats.cache.id), :target => "_blank"  %></td>
```

Which produces N+1 queries like the following:

```
 Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Keyword Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "keywords".* FROM "keywords" WHERE "keywords"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "statistics" WHERE "statistics"."keyword_id" = $1  [["keyword_id", 1]]
  Statistic Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "statistics".* FROM "statistics" WHERE "statistics"."keyword_id" = $1  ORDER BY "statistics"."word" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0  [["keyword_id", 1]]
  Cache Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "caches".* FROM "caches" WHERE "caches"."statistic_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["statistic_id", 5]]
  Cache Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "caches".* FROM "caches" WHERE "caches"."statistic_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["statistic_id", 4]]
  Cache Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "caches".* FROM "caches" WHERE "caches"."statistic_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["statistic_id", 3]]
  Cache Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "caches".* FROM "caches" WHERE "caches"."statistic_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["statistic_id", 2]]
  Cache Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "caches".* FROM "caches" WHERE "caches"."statistic_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["statistic_id", 1]]
  Rendered statistics/show.html.erb within layouts/application (13.7ms)
```

Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: You might have to, or even want to - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26251892/525478

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

ActiveRecord has a method called includes, which ensures that all the associated datas specified are loaded with the minimum number of queries.

```
def show
  @keyword = Keyword.find(params[:id])
  @statistics = @keyword.statistics.includes(:cache).order("statistics.word").paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page]
end
```

Comment: stats.cache.id (your codes) is different that stats.cache_id (mine)

Comment: It throws out the following error: ``undefined method `cache_id' for #<Statistic:0x007fbb6a2c8d28>``

Comment: also I found good article about [N+1 Problem](http://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/)

Comment: [How to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?lq=1)