# Rails 5, @child.parent, N+1 bullet

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Rails 5.

New app, all default.

Bullet gem tell me this:

```
user: root
/children/2
N+1 Query detected
  Child => [:parent]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:parent]
N+1 Query method call stack
  app/controllers/children_controller.rb:14:in `show'
app/controllers/children_controller.rb:14:in `show'
```

I have these **models**:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :children

end

class Child < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :parent

end
```

I have this controller in **children_controller.rb** with:

```
...

def show
    @parent = @child.parent
end
...
```

In my views **views/children/show.html.erb** I have this:

```
...
<%= @parent.name %>
...
```

If I invert this and in view I put:

```
<%= @child.parent.name %>
```

and in controller:

```
...

def show
    #nothing more
end
...
```

I have the same error from Bullet but in html.

**How to fix this? Is really a N+1 problem or Bullet is wrong?**

The project is really really new. First models.

Comment: Hi: please check that the value of @child in your show action (in the controller) is not nil. You'll have to fetch the record somehow: e.g. '@child = Child.first to see if it's working?

Comment: You might get a kick out of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247288/reducing-n1-queries-using-the-bullet-and-rspec-gems and

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, it's not nil.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its a N+1 problem as a child has only one parent. However, you can use includes, if that makes a difference:

```
@child = Child.includes(:parent).find(1)
```

But if you try both on terminal, you will see that ActiveRecord generates 2 SQL statements with and without the includes.

Comment: Now there are two queries. I think it's a bug in gem bullet. I can't believe I have to call it like this.

Comment: Create a issue on github to discuss your experience.